# How to make hightcharts tooltip scrollable after it displays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am using `highcharts` and I have define my own tooltip formatter returns a table wrapped by a div so there is a scroll bar if there are too many data.

I wrote a quick demo to show the problem here [demo_not_able_to_scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/cdyv0ctx/)

The problem is if the each charts get too closed, the user will not be able to get the mouse entered the tooltip , **because when they move the mouse a little, another tooltip shows**, but they must get their mouse into the tooltip or they can NOT scroll down to see the rest results.

Are there any ways that **I can let the tooltip scrollable without the mouse entered, like let it focus** after the tooltip show up?

My formmater are something like:

```
options.tooltip.formatter = function () {
    var s='<div style="padding:5px;"><b>' + xName +' </b></div> '+
                '<div style="max-height:250px ;min-width: 170px; overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden ">'+ //make a scroll bar to y axis when over 250px
                    '<table style="width: 150px">';
                     +......'</table></div>'
     return s  
}
```

Comment: Could you replicate an issue as live demo on the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan , yes, please check my quick static demo to show the problem ,http://jsfiddle.net/cdyv0ctx/

Answer (score -1):

You can disable defult tooltip, and prepare extra div (positioned absolutely). Then catch mouseOver event on the point and fill tooltip with content, setting correct position.

```
 plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stickyTracking: true,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            mouseOver: function (e) {
                                receive = 'y: ' + this.y;

                                $('#customTooltip').html(receive)
                                .css({
                                    top: e.target.plotY,
                                    left:  e.target.plotX
                                })
                                .show();
                            },

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/Lhzyfrzt/11/

Comment: Thank you for your helo, but I can' see the scroolbar in your demo, I just want to let it scrollable, not want to change their position.

Comment: So add a div with scrollbar inside, it is only simple demo.

Comment: Well, your demo also does not share the tooltip(shared=true), how could it possible to have my problem? Do you mean that I display a brand new tooltip on my own and let that tool tip focus by catching the mouseOver() event?